# IHttpHandler : execution performance

Tags: c#, iis-7, ihttphandler

I have a c# code written with IHttpHandler interface. When I execute it for the first time it takes 4-5 seconds to work. But after second execution, it works much more faster. For example when I execute it again after 1 hour it again takes 4-5 second to work.

My Question : How can I make my program works faster for the whole time? Should it configured from IIS part or c# part?

My sample Process request function:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        context.Response.Write(String.Format("<h1>{0}</h1>", dt.ToLongTimeString()));

    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this other stackoverflow answer, might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775256/how-to-improve-startup-performance-on-iis-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

IIS shutdowns your application domain after a given idle time (20 min by default).

So the next time you issue a request for that application, IIS will start that application domain again, and that is why it is responding slow the first time you try after one hour.